# Refresh Listview not working after dialog box

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Refresh not working in Listview; Already looked up many other responses on similar topics but could not solve the problem.

1. listview with order items + a button that opens a dialog box to set the quantity.
2. the database is updated from within dialog with the quantity that users enters manually; that works.
3. return from dialog box back to listview layout does not refresh content of db.
4. when I click on a button on main activity to show the listview again, yes then the db contents is shown.

How can I make it refresh automatically? I have tried `.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `.invalidate()` without success.

Here is the code:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chkImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="28dp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the main activity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    currentOrderNumber = getCurrentOrderNumber();

    od_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    txtViewOrderCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.orderCount);  
    txtViewCatalogCount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.catalogCount);  

    buildUpCurrentOrderList();
    addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
    button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
          buildUpCurrentOrderList();
            }
});
    private void buildUpCurrentOrderList () {
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        S_DAO db = new S_DAO(this) ;
        db.open();
        db.set_orderdetailChangedToN(this);
        list.clear();

        List<OrderDetail> orderdetails = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
        orderdetails = db.getOrderDetailList();
        orderCount=orderdetails.size();
        final ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderdetailsReverse = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>(orderdetails);
        Collections.reverse(orderdetailsReverse);

        final CustomOrderViewAdapter adapter = new CustomOrderViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.scans_list, orderdetailsReverse);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);  

        txtViewOrderCount.setText(Integer.toString(orderCount)); 
        txtViewOrderCount.bringToFront();


     }
```

Here is the adapter code:

```
public class CustomOrderViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OrderDetail>  {

    Context context;

    public CustomOrderViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<OrderDetail> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtBarcode;
    TextView txtDesc;
    TextView txtBrand;
    TextView txtMeasure;
    TextView txtWeightVol;
    TextView txtPackItems;
    TextView txtQuantity;
    CheckBox chkImage;
    ImageView icon;
    ImageButton buttonMore;
}
public void updateOrderdetailList() {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewholder = null;
    final OrderDetail orderdetail = getItem(position);
    final int pos = position;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scans_list, null);
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();

        viewholder.txtBarcode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.barcode);
        viewholder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        viewholder.txtBrand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.brand);
        viewholder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        viewholder.txtMeasure = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.measure);
        viewholder.txtWeightVol = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weightvol);
        viewholder.txtPackItems = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packitems);
        viewholder.txtQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        viewholder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);
        viewholder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        viewholder.buttonMore = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMore);

        convertView.setTag(viewholder);
    } else
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    viewholder.txtBarcode.setText(orderdetail.get_od_p_Barcode());
    S_DAO db = new S_DAO(context) ;
    db.open();
    final String tmpBarcode=orderdetail.get_od_p_Barcode();
    final String tmpDesc = db.readProduct(context, tmpBarcode).get_p_DescLong();
    final int tmpPackItems =db.readProduct(context, tmpBarcode).get_p_PackItems();
    final int tmpWeightVol = db.readProduct(context, tmpBarcode).get_p_WeightVol();
    final int tmpQuantity=orderdetail.get_od_Quantity();

    viewholder.txtBrand.setText(db.readProduct(context, tmpBarcode).get_p_Brand());
    viewholder.txtDesc.setText(tmpDesc);
    viewholder.txtMeasure.setText(db.readProduct(context, tmpBarcode).get_p_Measure());
    viewholder.txtWeightVol.setText(Integer.toString(tmpWeightVol));
    viewholder.txtPackItems.setText(Integer.toString(tmpPackItems));
    viewholder.txtQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(tmpQuantity));

    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(db.readProduct(context, tmpBarcode).get_p_ImageName(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    db.close();

    viewholder.imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);

    viewholder.buttonMore.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            orderdetailDialog(orderdetail, tmpPackItems, tmpDesc, tmpQuantity, pos, v, parent);


        }
        });


    viewholder.icon.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            setCyan(orderdetail, parent, pos, v);
        }
        });


    viewholder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setCyan(orderdetail, parent, pos, v);
        }
        });

    return convertView;


}
```

in the same adapter class : the class to open the dialog box

```
public void orderdetailDialog (final OrderDetail orderdetail, int itemsPerPack, String p_desc, int p_quantity, int pos, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater factory = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.scans_more, null);
     //text_entry is an Layout XML file containing two text field to display in alert dialog
     final EditText  inputQuantity = (EditText ) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
     final TextView  inputItemsPerPack = (TextView ) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.itemsPerPack);             

     inputQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(p_quantity), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
     inputItemsPerPack.setText(Integer.toString(itemsPerPack), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

     final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

     alert.setIcon(R.drawable.more2)
          .setTitle(p_desc)
          .setView(textEntryView)
          .setPositiveButton("Save", 
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      updateOrderDetail(orderdetail, Integer.parseInt(inputQuantity.getText().toString()));

                  }
              })
          .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                         int whichButton) {
                  }
              });
     alert.show();
}
```

then the class to update the database:

```
 private void updateOrderDetail (OrderDetail orderdetail, int quantity) {

        S_DAO db = new S_DAO(context) ;
        db.open();
        db.updateOrderDetailWithQuantity(context, orderdetail, quantity);
        db.close();   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `UIThread`? Like that

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and call it in where your database updated.

```
    private void updateOrderDetail (OrderDetail orderdetail, int quantity) {
        S_DAO db = new S_DAO(context) ;
        db.open();
        List<OrderDetail> orderdetails = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
        db.updateOrderDetailWithQuantity(context, orderdetail, quantity);
        orderdetails = db.getOrderDetailList();
        final ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderdetailsReverse = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>(orderdetails);
        Collections.reverse(orderdetailsReverse);
        clear();
        addAll(orderdetailsReverse);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
        }
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: I added it inside the adaper: but no success                      private void buildUpCurrentOrderList () {
 ...
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
     });
 
    }

Comment: Not there You should add this where you update your list, it is updateOrderDetail function.

Comment: GREAT !  that does it !  Thank you so much.  Fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the invalidate() or the postInvalidate() method anywhere?? You have to call one of them the moment that you want to refresh the table.

Comment: i guess inside the onClick handler you should call od_listview.invalidate();